# How to validate Google/Gmail OAuth2 token in Asp.net Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, google-chrome-extension, asp.net-web-api2

In my chrome extension I have an access token retrieved from Google's end point (using getAuthToken()).  I'd like to pass the token to my Asp.net Web API server in http headers.  However, I'm not sure how I could validate the token on the server side?  That is, how do I make sure that the token belongs to a given user and it is not a fake?

Do I need to pass the token to a Google's end point to validate it?  If yes, how do I do that from Web API?

Thanks